# Perl :: Accessing Members of an Object with `use strict` Set?

Tags: perl, object, syntax, member

I'm a Java/C/C#/python coder who is attempting his first Perl script, and I have what is prob a Perl OOO 101 question:  What is the syntax to access an object's members when `use strict` is required?

Let me speak Java for a moment.  I have this little program, all in one class file:

```
class Dude{
    public String name;
    public Dude(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void IntroduceYourself(){
        System.out.println("Hi, I'm "+this.name);
    }
}

public toy(){
    Dude fred = new Dude("Fred");
    fred.IntroduceYourself();
}
```

Output on my Ubuntu machine:

```
me@ubuntu01:~/$ java toy
Hi, I'm Fred
me@ubuntu01:~/$
```

What could be simpler?  I create a `Dude` object, then later call method `Dude.IntroduceYourself()`, which accesses a class member.

Okay:  I have to do the exact same thing, but now in Perl (v5.26.1).  Again, `use strict;` is required.  Here's my miserable attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# Define a "Dude" class
package Dude;
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
                _name => shift,
               };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
sub IntroduceYourself
{
        print("Hi, I'm $object->{name}\n");     # Compilation Error here!
}

my $object = new Dude("Fred");
$object->IntroduceYourself();
```

Output on the same Ubuntu machine:

```
me@ubuntu01:~/$ ./toyPerl.pl
Global symbol "$Dude" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $Dude"?) at ./toyPerl.pl line 18.
Execution of ./toyPerl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
me@ubuntu01:~/$
```

Ugh.  I've been reading a few Perl tutorials, and I see examples on how to write that `IntroduceYourself()` subroutine, but none with `use strict` as a global directive.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Also:  I'm really confused about what I'll call "member functions" in Perl.  In my Java example, `Dude.IntroduceYourself()` was defined as a method of class `Dude`.  I intend (if possible) for `IntroduceYourself()` to be a function of Object/Class `Dude` in the Perl code.  But its unclear to me how to define that.  Am I misunderstanding how Perl objects handle member functions?  Thank you.

Comment: There's no `$Dude` in your posted code. It seems you've posted the wrong code. The code you posted has a similar error about `$object`.

Comment: For one, I'd suggest looking for a more modern and established tutorial -- at least judged by that `new Dude()...`, which abuses a certain feature. That's for years been pounded everywhere to be written as a normal method call, which it is, `Dude->new()`.    I'm guessing, old outdated sources...?

Comment: @zdim This is an excellent point.  To learn new code, I'm a big believer in just jumping into the deep end of the pool and start coding.  That can be a great way to learn, but when you do this, you don't realize when you're learning from outdated material.  Thanks for the pro tip!

Comment: "_...deep end of the pool..._"  -- by all means, yes!  But wear good swimwear :).  I don't know your style, but [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/) has a lot of no-nonsense excellent material; not an easy way to start but then it's generally the best info.  On the other end, there is an online book [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/); all I saw from it was good. (And of course there are good books to purchase but that's yet another topic...)   I don't know on top of my head of good short tutorials.  Have fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
sub IntroduceYourself {
   my $self = shift;
   print( "Hi, I'm $self->{ _name }\n" );
}
```

See [perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut).

---

In OOP, the invocant (the value of the expression before the `.`/`->`) is passed to the method as an argument. In Java, this argument is made available as `this`. In Perl, this argument is made available as a leading parameter.

This means that

```perl
$o->foo( $x, $y )
```

is equivalent to

```perl
my $method = $o->can( 'foo' );
$method->( $o, $x, $y )
```

And the method looks like this:

```perl
sub foo {
   my $self = shift;
   my $x    = shift;
   my $y    = shift;

   $self->{ x } = $x;
   $self->{ y } = $y;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't have to do with OO, just Perl's normal [`strict`](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) behavior. `strict` forces you to declare variables, like in other languages. Without `strict`, undeclared objects are globals. `$object` is never declared, so it violates strict.

To solve this, `$object` must be declared. Perl's `this` is passed in as the first argument to a method. You need to get that argument. Perl calls this the "invocant". Typically it is called `$self`.

> *What is the syntax to access an object's members*

Perl doesn't have object members like Java. A Perl object is just a reference. It doesn't even need to be a hash reference. `$self->{key}` is just using a hash reference, so the key has to match. `$self->{_name}` not `$self->{name}`.

```
sub IntroduceYourself {
    # Get the invocant off the list of arguments.
    my $self = shift;

    # Use it as a hash reference with the correct key.
    print("Hi, I'm $self->{_name}\n");
}
```

> *I intend (if possible) for IntroduceYourself() to be a function of Object/Class Dude in the Perl code. But its unclear to me how to define that.*

You did it. A class is just a package. A method is just a subroutine in a package. The language does not make a distinction between subroutines and methods, nor between class and object methods. It's just how you use them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo {
  sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my($name) = @_;

    return bless { name => $name }, $class;
  }

  sub hello {
    my $self = shift;
    print "Hello my name is $self->{name}\n";
  }
}

my $foo = Foo->new("Pete");

# Called as an object method.
$foo->hello;

# Called as a subroutine.
# It works, but don't do it; it bypasses inheritance.
Foo::hello($foo);

# Called as a class method.
# It "works", but since the method expects $self to be a
# reference, not a package name, $self->{name} is... it's complicated.
Foo->hello;
```

Perl's OO is extremely basic. You get classes (via packages), multiple-inheritance (via @ISA), and methods (via subroutines with the invocant passed in) and that's about it. No accessors, no public, no private, no members, not even `this`.

If you want that, you have to write it yourself, or use an existing library. If you want all the bells and whistles and a full marching band, install [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose).

---

> *...use strict as a global directive...*

`use strict` is not global, it is local to the current scope. The current scope is the whole file, but you can put it in a block.

```
{
  # strict is on in this block
  use strict;
  my $foo = 42;
  print "$foo\n";
}

# strict is off everywhere else
$bar = 23;
print "$bar\n";
```

Things like `strict` and `warnings` are referred to as "pragmas".

See ["What's the difference between dynamic and lexical (static) scoping? Between local() and my()?"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7#What%27s-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-lexical-(static)-scoping?-Between-local()-and-my()?).